# Powershell Select-String -pattern -notMatch

Tags: powershell, select-string

I have lines -

```
echo $LocalAdmins
    Administrator
    Domain-Administrator
    daemon
    SomeUser
```

- Line 1-3 should be same although there could be situation where
  Domain-Administrator doesn't exist so simply counting lines won't
  help because User might hide in 3rd line.
- Line 4 string changes, there could be more than 4 lines either as
  well as no Line 4 at all.
- I'm not sure yet if lines change their position or not.

I need to get string that is -notMatch "Administrator", "Domain-Administrator", "daemon". I.e., I need user names that are in this list.

Is there a way to use more than one -notMatch with -and or ()? Currently I'm stuck with code that use only one -notMatch. And I can't use -Match because there could be 2+ users in the list.

```
$LocalAdmins | Select-String -pattern "Administrator" -notMatch
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this?

```
$LocalAdmins | select-string -Pattern 'Administrator|daemon' -NotMatch | select -expa line
```

`-pattern` accepts `REGEX`. You can use the `|` ( or regex operator ) to add others words to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `$LocalAdmins` is an array you could do this:

```
$exclude = 'Administrator', 'Domain-Administrator', 'daemon'
$LocalAdmins | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ }
```